# Localizable.strings in German

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I am localizing an app into German using Localizable.string.
All well until I need to use a ü or ß type letter in the localized string.

I get an error when building.

```
de.lproj/Localizable.strings:0: error: validation failed: The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted.
```

Example;

"Simple introductions and alphabet" = "Einfache Begrüßungen und das Aphabet";

Anyone out there with a solution?
Thanks

Comment: Is Localizable.strings in UTF8?

Comment: How do I know? Where does one set that?

Comment: Had the some problem on a project where multiple developers had different encodings. Works with utf8 now.

Comment: How do I go about to change it to UTF8 ?

Comment: @Jorgen Select the file, press ⌥⌘1.

Comment: Found it in Prefs. It's set to UTF8.  Should I change to something else?

Comment: @Jano. Found it!  Thanks a million!

Comment: Is now all working fine?

Comment: I hope nobody will be offended if I'll post solution in response to a question. So the rest will be easier to find a solution

Comment: It's the right thing to do Nekto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After conversation in comments the problem was solved.

If you will have similar problem then first of all you should check **text encoding** of file where error occurred. You can find current text encoding and change it in `Xcode`:

1. Open file in Xcode.
2. Press ⌥⌘1 (thanks [@Jano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412916/jano))
3. Find field `Text Encoding`
4. Set it to `Unicode (UTF-8)`
5. Try to rebuild the project

Answer (score 7):

In my case neither of the other answers fixed my problem. After spending some time with searching for help, I somehow noticed I forgot a semicolon on the end of a line.
Admittedly this is a really basic error on my behalf, but the compiler could have told me my mistake instead of:

```
Validation failed: The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted.
```

So remember that strings table files have to be in the format

```
"Key" = "Localized Value goes here";
```